# How to login to webpage for webscraping when using Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to connect to a webpage with login credentials to web scrape it, but I am not sure if I do it correctly because I get no results only the URLs.

I do the following

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":


    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get('MyloginURL')

    username = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
    username.send_keys('myemail')

    password = browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
    time.sleep(4)
    password.send_keys('mypassword')

    sing_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="send2"]')
    sing_in.click()


    with Pool(4) as p:
     records = p.map(parse, web_links)

    if len(records) > 0:
         with open('output_global.csv', 'a') as f:
          f.write('\n'.join(records))
```

With the above I am using the same session? Do I use a proper way with my current example?

Comment: what is your output? Does your webdriver not continue to the page behind the login? Also, what are you trying to search for on the page ? If you want to scrape the site you can use BEAUTIFULSOUP to scrape it nicely

Comment: When I use it I login ok but when I start scraping the page I get only the urls and not the data, like price and availability of the supplier

Comment: you have defined in your parse, web_links. this may be why you only see urls, Look up beautiful soup and how to use it to scrape the data of the site. It is much better to use it for scraping data.

Comment: if you are asking if this is correct to login to a webpage then yes it is. There are also other correct ways to login. But there is nothing wrong with what you habve done...

Comment: never share a single webndriver instance between multiple processes.

Comment: so how can I do it?

Comment: That's not going to work. Use scrapy if you want concurrency.

Comment: What if I use something like session ?